# Autocomplete sometimes doesn't show results from server

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Explanation of the code is below.

Here is the autocomplete I am using (but I've examined 3 other autocomplete packages, and they all behave the same way):

https://goodies.pixabay.com/javascript/auto-complete/demo.html

And here is how I am using it on the client side (note that I am using autocomplete in conjunction with *socket.io* so that I can update my autocomplete as users type into the search box):

```
socket.on('searchBarResults', function(data) {

var my_autoComplete = new autoComplete({
    selector: 'input[name="searchbar4"]',
    minChars: 1,
    cache: false,
    source: function(term, suggest){
        term = term.toLowerCase();
        var choices = [
            data[0]._source.movie
        ];
        var matches = [];
        for (i=0; i<choices.length; i++)
            if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) matches.push(choices[i]);
        suggest(matches);
    }
});

    $searchBar4.on('input', function(event){
        my_autoComplete.destroy();
    });
});
```

So here is what all this is doing: when the user starts to input the name of the movie, after every word they enter the server searches the database for a match, and sends the results to the client.

For example: if the user searches **Star**, the server will send back **Star Trek Undiscovered Country**, and the searchbox will show an *autocomplete option* called **Star Trek Undiscovered Country**.

That's works well and all.

If the user types **Star Trek** the server will, again, send back **Star Trek Undiscovered Country**, and the autocomplete will update. That's fine.

Here is the issue I have:

If the user types **Star Country**, the server *will* send back **Star Trek Undiscovered Country**, but the *autocomplete* won't display it.

The autocomplete will only display results if the words *are in order* (you can't skip words).

How can I get autocomplete to **always** show the results from the server, no matter what order a user inputs words into the search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your:

```
if (~choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) matches.push(choices[i]);
```

It will remove all items that doesn't match the term.

`"Star Trek Undiscovered Country".toLowerCase().indexOf("Star Country")`

It will return -1 since it doesn't contain that entire string. You need to split it into words and compare them one by one.

You should be able to do something like this:

```js
var match = function(term, suggest){
        term = term.toLowerCase();

        // for debugging.
        var choices = new Array();
        choices.push('Star Trek Undiscovered Country');

        var matches = [];
        for (i=0; i<choices.length; i++)
        {
            var allMatches = true;
            var words = term.split(' '); // Split into words and check them individually.

            //TODO: Possibly handle case when there is only one word.

            for(var y = 0; y<words.length; y++)
            {
                // Check if this word is in choices[i].
                if (choices[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(words[y]) == -1)
                {
                    // Not a match.
                    allMatches = false;
                    // Possibly continue when allMatches == false, since the following words doesn't matter.
                }
            }
            if(allMatches)
            {
                matches.push(choices[i]);
            }
        }
        suggest(matches);
    }

var suggest = function(item){
  console.log(item);
};
match('Star Country', suggest); // Returns one item.
match('Star Blaster', suggest); // Returns no items.
```

Also, it seems as `choices` will always be an array with 1 item? Why do you use an array for it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. Specifically, regarding `indexOf(word) == -1` it is saying about the use of `(word)`: *Possible iteration over unexpected (custom/inherited) members, probably missing hasOwnPropery...*

Comment: Okay, I changed `indexOf(word) == -1` to `indexOf(word) == 0` and it initially seems to be working. If I type **Star Country** I am now getting the full **Star Trek Undiscovered Country** result. I am going to do more testing and confirm later.

Comment: Yeah, it was wrong. I've updated the code with a working snippet.

Comment: @MonkeyOnARock - Do not use indexOf(word) == 0, since it checks if it's the first word in the string. Use the updated sample with the proper for-loop instead.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. As for your overall solution, it is working perfectly. Thank you so much!